# Creating a counter from columns in a dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I asked this question before and didn't ask it correctly so I will try it again I have a dataset that uses pandas and numpy mainly I am trying to take columns with Employee IDs (Also includes managers' IDs):

```
emp_id      mgr_id 
   1          3
   2          3
   3          5      
   4          3
   5          7
   6          7 
   7          10
   8          3
   9          7
   10         -
```

I have something similar to this where I want the ID of the employee manager or not to show how many people report to them and I want a counter like this:

```
emp_id     mgr_id     emp_count
   1         3            0
   2         3            0 
   3         5            4
   4         3            0
   5         7            1
   6         7            0 
   7         10           3
   8         3            0
   9         7            0
   10        -            1
```

my code looks like this:

```
 df['emp_count'] = df.groupby('mgr_id').transform('count')
```

when I run this I get an error of:

> Value Error: Cannot set a dataframe with multiple columns to the single column emp_count.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong I am pretty novice to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do

```
# Count of unique employee reporting to a manager
counts = df['emp_id'].groupby(df['mgr_id'].astype(str)).nunique()

# Map the counts to emp_id column
df['emp_count'] = df['emp_id'].astype(str).map(counts).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Result

```
   emp_id mgr_id  emp_count
0       1      3          0
1       2      3          0
2       3      5          4
3       4      3          0
4       5      7          1
5       6      7          0
6       7     10          3
7       8      3          0
8       9      7          0
9      10      -          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approch, but not as elegant as Shubham's answer

```
    df['emp_id'] = df['emp_id'].astype(str)
    df['mgr_id'] = df['mgr_id'].astype(str)
    df1 = df.groupby('mgr_id').count().reset_index().rename(columns={'emp_id': 'count', 'mgr_id': 'emp_id'})
    df2 = df.merge(df1, how='left', on='emp_id')
    df2['count'] = df2['count'].fillna(0)
```

Result

```
enter code here

    emp_id mgr_id  count
0      1      3    0
1      2      3    0
2      3      5    4
3      4      3    0
4      5      7    1
5      6      7    0
6      7     10    3
7      8      3    0
8      9      7    0
9     10      -    1
```